# How can you merge two objects into same property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, merge

I have 2 separate JS objects which need to be merged into the same property.

The objects currently look like this:

Object 1:

```
[0:{"acircuit":"ABCDEFGH","astatus":"Test"}, 1:{"acircuit":"IJKLMNOP","astatus":"Test2"}]
```

Object 2:

```
[0:{"bcircuit":"ABCDEFGH","bstatus":"Test3"}, 1:{"bcircuit":"IJKLMNOP","bstatus":"Test4"}]
```

I need to merge these results into one so it appears as the following:

```
[
    0:{"acircuit":"ABCDEFGH","astatus":"Test","bcircuit":"ABCDEFGH","bstatus":"Test3"}, 
    1:{"acircuit":"IJKLMNOP","astatus":"Test2","bcircuit":"IJKLMNOP","bstatus":"Test4"}
]
```

Current code looks like this:

```
allResults = {this.state.aCircuitResults.concat(this.state.bCircuitResults)}
```

However, the results appear like this:

```
[
    0:{"acircuit":"ABCDEFGH","astatus":"Test"},
    1:{"acircuit":"IJKLMNOP","astatus":"Test2"}
    2:{"bcircuit":"ABCDEFGH","bstatus":"Test3"}, 
    3:{"bcircuit":"IJKLMNOP","bstatus":"Test4"}
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), assuming you want to combine them by where they are in the arrays:

```
const result = firstArray.map((firstObject, index) => Object.assign({}, firstObject, secondArray[index]));
```

Example:

```js
const firstArray = [{"acircuit":"ABCDEFGH","astatus":"Test"},{"acircuit":"IJKLMNOP","astatus":"Test2"}];

const secondArray = [{"bcircuit":"ABCDEFGH","bstatus":"Test3"},{"bcircuit":"IJKLMNOP","bstatus":"Test4"}];

const result = firstArray.map((firstObject, index) => Object.assign({}, firstObject, secondArray[index]));

console.log(result);
```

If you need to relate them by a property (say, `acircuit` and `bcircuit`), build a `Map` from one of them keyed by the property, then you can use a lookup in the `map` operation:

```
const second = new Map(secondArray.map(obj => [obj.bcircuit, obj]));
const result = firstArray.map(firstObject => Object.assign({}, firstObject, second.get(firstObject.acircuit)));
```

Example:

```js
const firstArray = [{"acircuit":"ABCDEFGH","astatus":"Test"},{"acircuit":"IJKLMNOP","astatus":"Test2"}];

const secondArray = [{"bcircuit":"ABCDEFGH","bstatus":"Test3"},{"bcircuit":"IJKLMNOP","bstatus":"Test4"}];

const second = new Map(secondArray.map(obj => [obj.bcircuit, obj]));
const result = firstArray.map(firstObject => Object.assign({}, firstObject, second.get(firstObject.acircuit)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That worked - Thanks for your help and quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in combination with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const result = arrayA.map((a, i) => ({...a, ...arrayB[i]}));
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const arrayA = [{"acircuit":"ABCDEFGH","astatus":"Test"}, {"acircuit":"IJKLMNOP","astatus":"Test2"}];
const arrayB = [{"bcircuit":"ABCDEFGH","bstatus":"Test3"}, {"bcircuit":"IJKLMNOP","bstatus":"Test4"}];

const result = arrayA.map((a, i) => ({...a, ...arrayB[i]}));

console.log(result);
```